# Backbone.js, IE 8 and Win 7

Tags: backbone.js

Just started to work in `backbone.js` and asp.net. The code is working fine in Firefox and the same code is not working in IE 8. Do I need to config something to make it work in IE 8?

Console.log works only in Firefox, not sure where to see the logged messsage in IE8 (already using the developer tool of IE 8).

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In IE 8 you can go to the "Script" tab (you'll see it on the left where there's HTML, CSS, Script, and Profiler tabs) and the console is on the right hand side in that tab.

And the answer to your first question is no, there's nothing special for Backbone.js and IE, you probably have some JavaScript that is perfectly standards compliant and of course, IE 8 doesn't like it.

For example, don't end a list with a trailing comma:

```
{
  "something" : "value",
  "other" : "different value",
}
```

would be fine in Firefox, not-so-much in IE.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this on my last project. Items like the one mentioned by John can be flagged by running your code through jslint. The trailing comma was my biggest offender

You can use http://www.jslint.com/ and cut down on some of the errors and warning that are not related to running in IE.